# Multiple select-option mysql query on multiple tables

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to build a query that depends on the selected options of a form. I think I have got through this but don't think It looks as efficient as I think it could have been (If I show you the script you would think that reading the bible wouldn't take so long) . I would like to see whether any of you is so kind to propose any idea to get it more efficient.

Users have to select two things:

First, what kind of invoice(albaran) they want to be shown, (paid(pagado), open(pte), without issuing(sin factura), all of them(todos)).
Second, what client the invoice(albaran) is referred to, (a particular one or all of them(todos)).
Invoices and clients are two different mysql tables that share the ref_cliente column

All this is selected in, say, page1.php and when the form is filled and sent with a post method the page reloads "activating" the scripts with the array $_POST loades.

Thanks for your time and interest!

**Editing question to add OP's table schema**

`TABLE clientes (columns: ref_cliente, nombre, nif)`
`TABLE facturas (columns: ref_factura, ref_cliente, estado)`

`estado` is a varchar column that indicates whether the invoice has been paid, not paid or not issued. (boolean effect)

Comment: Please show us your table schema :-)

Comment: Sorry for being so ambiguous.

Comment: Sorry for being so ambiguous. The database is built as follows: TABLE clientes (columns: ref_cliente, nombre, nif) TABLE facturas (columns: ref_factura, ref_cliente, estado) estado is a varchar column that indicates whether the invoice has been paid, not paid or not issued. I hope this helps. If not please, tell me haw can I kind of import the information of the mysql database. Thanks again

Answer (score 0):

As bonCodigo said, if you show the table schema, it is problably easier to help... But, I'll do a try.

I would set this up with two parameters "status" and "client", then the SQL has to be build according to the values of those parameters. I am using PDO

Like:

```
$sql="SELECT * from invoices i, clients c where c.ref_cliente=i.ref_cliente";
$params=array();
if($_POST['status']!='todos'){
   $sql.=' and i.status=?';
   $params[]=$_POST['status'];
}
if($_POST['clients']!='todos'){
   $sql.=' and c.ref_cliente=?';
   $params[]=$_POST['clients'];
}
$sqlh=$dbh->prepare($sql); // $dbh must be set up, see the PDO-documentation
$sqlh->execute($params);
```

Comment: Sorry for being so ambiguous. The database is built as follows: TABLE clientes (columns: ref_cliente, nombre, nif) TABLE facturas (columns: ref_factura, ref_cliente, estado) estado is a varchar column that indicates whether the invoice has been paid, not paid or not issued. I hope this helps. If not please, tell me haw can I kind of import the information of the mysql database. Thanks again

Comment: It's OK, did you try what I set up?

Answer (score 0):

Alright, take a look at the following code snippet. As Morten Sickel said, we tried to provide some help to you. BTW is your `NIF` refers to numéro d'identification fiscale? Shouldn't it be `varchar`? I have created accordingly adn please put the right details and types you need.

**Reference:**

### [SQLFIDDLE](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/da1bb/14)

In the above sample, I have put multiple simple queries that you have mentioned based on your Form's drop-down selection. E.g. Paid invoices based on a client, Unpaid Invoices based on a client, Count all paid for each client, unpaid for each client, display all invoices (paid, unpaid) for each client etc...

**MySQL Query:**

```
//-- show todos facturas/cliente
SELECT c.*,f.*
FROM clientes c, facturas f
WHERE c.ref_cliente = f.ref_cliente
ORDER BY c.ref_cliente
;

//-- show pagado(paid) facturas/cliente
SELECT c.*,f.*
FROM clientes c, facturas f
WHERE c.ref_cliente = f.ref_cliente
AND f.estado = 'Paid'
ORDER BY c.ref_cliente
;

//-- show pte(open/unpaid) facturas/cliente
SELECT c.*,f.*
FROM clientes c, facturas f
WHERE c.ref_cliente = f.ref_cliente
AND f.estado = 'NotPaid'
ORDER BY c.ref_cliente
;

//-- count number of paid, unpaid facturas/cliente
SELECT c.*, 
COUNT(CASE WHEN f.estado = 'Paid'
THEN f.ref_cliente END) AS PAID,
COUNT(CASE WHEN f.estado = 'NotPaid'
THEN f.ref_cliente END) AS NOTPAID
FROM clientes c, facturas f
WHERE c.ref_cliente=f.ref_cliente
GROUP BY c.ref_cliente
;

//-- with a group concat to show paid/open facturas/cliente
SELECT c.*, 
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN f.estado = 'Paid'
THEN f.ref_factura END) AS PAID,
GROUP_CONCAT(CASE WHEN f.estado = 'NotPaid'
THEN f.ref_factura END) AS UNPAID
FROM clientes c, facturas f
WHERE c.ref_cliente=f.ref_cliente
GROUP BY f.ref_cliente
;
```

**Results:** for each of the abovce query.

```
REF_CLIENTE     NOMBRE  NIF         REF_FACTURA     ESTADO
1               428     57432844Z   1001A           Paid
1               428     57432844Z   1005D           NotPaid
2               418     67832814K   1002B           NotPaid
2               418     67832814K   1001B           NotPaid
2               418     67832814K   1002A           Paid
3               438     87932854F   1001C           Paid
4               448     97232834S   1003A           Paid


REF_CLIENTE     NOMBRE  NIF         REF_FACTURA     ESTADO
1               428     57432844Z   1001A           Paid
2               418     67832814K   1002A           Paid
3               438     87932854F   1001C           Paid
4               448     97232834S   1003A           Paid


REF_CLIENTE     NOMBRE  NIF         REF_FACTURA     ESTADO
1               428     57432844Z   1005D           NotPaid
2               418     67832814K   1002B           NotPaid
2               418     67832814K   1001B           NotPaid

//-- count number of paid, unpaid facturas/cliente
REF_CLIENTE     NOMBRE  NIF         PAID    NOTPAID
1               428     57432844Z   1       1
2               418     67832814K   1       2
3               438     87932854F   1       0
4               448     97232834S   1       0

//-- with a group concat to show paid/open facturas/cliente
REF_CLIENTE     NOMBRE  NIF         PAID    UNPAID
1               428     57432844Z   1001A   1005D
2               418     67832814K   1002A   1002B,1001B
3               438     87932854F   1001C   (null)
4               448     97232834S   1003A   (null)
```

PS: Sorry I am not particularly using `PHP`, so you need to put the query into proper `PHP` syntax though. Parameters such as `estado` and `ref_cliente` are what you may be passing from form's drop-down/text field to trigger the database via sql. **MortenSickel** seem to be able to help you with that :P